# SQL Query to transpose rows into columns

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a .net web application that uses SQL Server 2008. The data table I am trying to display in a grid contains columns that are actually rows of another table. Right now, I am doing this in the BLL, reading data into data table; getting the data from another table and making it into columns of first data table and then going through each row of data in that data table to populate the new columns. Very time consuming and slow.

I believe this can be done through a query in SQL 2012 and above using "Transpose" or something similar but not sure if it is possible in 2008. I researched and tried using "pivot" but I am not good at SQL and couldn't get it to work.

This is a simplified example of DB tables and what I need to display:

```
Facility Table:
FacilityID
12345
67890

PartnerInfo table:
PartnerID    Partner
1            Partner1
2            Partner2
3            Partner3

FacilityPartner table:
FacilityID    PartnerID
12345         1
12345         3
67890         2
67890         3
```

Need a query to return something like:

```
FacilityID    Partner1    Partner2    Partner3
12345         true        false       true
67890         false       true        true
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should give some idea on pivoting the data. It doesn't give you exact true false as you asked.

```
    declare  @facility table (facilityId int)
    declare  @PartnerInfo  table (partnerid int, partnerN varchar(1000))
    declare  @FacilityPartner table (facilityId int,partnerid int)

    insert into @facility values (12345)
    insert into @facility values (67890)
    insert into @facility values (67891)

    insert into @PartnerInfo values (1, 'partner1')
    insert into @PartnerInfo values (2, 'partner2')
    insert into @PartnerInfo values (3, 'partner3')

    insert into @FacilityPartner values(12345, 1)
    insert into @FacilityPartner values(12345, 3)
    insert into @FacilityPartner values(67890, 2)
    insert into @FacilityPartner values(67890, 3)

    select f.facilityId as facid, p.PartnerN as partn, 100 as val
    FROM @facility f
    LEFT join @FacilityPartner fp on f.facilityId = fp.facilityId
    LEFT JOIN @PartnerInfo p on p.partnerid = fp.partnerid

    select facid, Partner1 , partner2,partner3 FROM 

    (select f.facilityId as facid, p.PartnerN as partn, 100 as val
    FROM @facility f
    LEFT join @FacilityPartner fp on f.facilityId = fp.facilityId
    LEFT JOIN @PartnerInfo p on p.partnerid = fp.partnerid) x
    PIVOT(
    avg(val)
    for partn in ([partner1], [partner2],[partner3])
    ) as pvt
```

Comment: what is p.PartnerN? Is it short for p.Partner1, p.Partner2, etc?

Comment: Partner seemed like a keyword and I was lazy to use [] so I named the column as PartnerN

Comment: I can combine what you listed here and Joel's suggestion of dynamically creating the query to achieve what I want. Just one question: How do I change the 100 and NULL outputs to true and false?

Comment: you can use case statement as case when Partner1 is NULL then 'false' else 'true' end as partner1

Comment: One last question: why are you using "avg(val)"?

Comment: When using Pivot, it is required to use an aggregate method, you can very well use Min or max. I put avg just because that's what i used when I had to use pivot.

Comment: Thank you. Marked yours as answer although I used option 2 of Joel's suggestion as well. Unfortunately cannot mark both as answer but I used your query to resolve the issue. It is a lot faster now.

Comment: I noticed an issue with this: if a facility is not associated with a partner, it is skipped which causes a problem if I am listing ALL facilities and their potential partners. The inner "Select" shows that. I tried changing the inner joins to left joins but that didn't help.

Comment: I updated the joins to left and added a facility that does not have any associated partner. When I execute that, I am seeing a row for the new facility too.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is, just like many other languages, SQL has a sort of "compile" process, where an execution plan is produced. An SQL query **MUST** be able to know the precise number and types of columns *at compile time,* without referencing the data (it does have some table metadata available for the compile, which is why `SELECT *` works).

This means what you want to do is only possible if one of two conditions is met:

1. You must know the precise number of partners (and the names for the columns, in this case) ahead of time. This is true even for a query using the PIVOT keyword.
2. You must be willing to do this in multiple steps, using dynamic SQL, where the first step looks at the data to know how many columns you'll need. Then you can build up a new query in a varchar variable, and finally execute that string using `Exec()` or`sp_executesql()`. This works because the last step invokes a new "compile" process and execution context for that string variable.

Of course there's also a third option: pivot the data in your client code. That is my preference. Most people, though, opt for option 2.

Comment: By "Pivot in your client code" I am assuming you are referring to what I am currently doing? I get the list of partner names, add them as columns to data table I had from a previous query (list of facilities), and then go row by row to populate the cells in new columns.

Comment: Something like that, yes, though I would tend to use formal Control/Break logic.