# SQL Query to transpose rows into columns - revisited

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a .net web application that uses SQL Server 2008. The data table I am trying to display in a grid contains columns that are actually rows of another table. Right now, I am doing this in the BLL, reading data into data table; getting the data from another table and making it into columns of first data table and then going through each row of data in that data table to populate the new columns. Very time consuming and slow.

I believe this can be done through a query in SQL 2012 and above using "Transpose" or something similar but not sure if it is possible in 2008. I researched and tried using "pivot" but I am not good at SQL and couldn't get it to work.

This is a simplified example of DB tables and what I need to display:

```
Facility Table:
FacilityID
12345
67890
99999

PartnerInfo table:
PartnerID    Partner
1            Partner1
2            Partner2
3            Partner3

FacilityPartner table:
FacilityID    PartnerID    Active
12345         1              1
12345         3              0
67890         2              1
67890         3              1
```

Need a query to return something like:

```
FacilityID    Partner1    Partner2    Partner3
12345         true        false       true
67890         false       true        true
99999         false       false       false
```

I posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701676/sql-query-to-transpose-rows-into-columns/44703415#44703415) and got a response that seemed to work (query below). However, when I the list of facilities, the query seems to exclude all those that have no partners (e.g. facility id 99999 does not get displayed). I tried playing with the query and changing inner joins to left joins but that didn't help.

```
declare  @facility table (facilityId int)
declare  @PartnerInfo  table (partnerid int, partnerN varchar(1000))
declare  @FacilityPartner table (facilityId int,partnerid int)

insert into @facility values (12345)
insert into @facility values (67890)

insert into @PartnerInfo values (1, 'partner1')
insert into @PartnerInfo values (2, 'partner2')
insert into @PartnerInfo values (3, 'partner3')

insert into @FacilityPartner values(12345, 1)
insert into @FacilityPartner values(12345, 3)
insert into @FacilityPartner values(67890, 2)
insert into @FacilityPartner values(67890, 3)

select f.facilityId as facid, p.PartnerN as partn, 100 as val
FROM @facility f
Inner join @FacilityPartner fp on f.facilityId = fp.facilityId
INNER JOIN @PartnerInfo p on p.partnerid = fp.partnerid

select facid, Partner1 , partner2,partner3 FROM 

(select f.facilityId as facid, p.PartnerN as partn, 100 as val
FROM @facility f
Inner join @FacilityPartner fp on f.facilityId = fp.facilityId
INNER JOIN @PartnerInfo p on p.partnerid = fp.partnerid) x
PIVOT(
avg(val)
for partn in ([partner1], [partner2],[partner3])
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing inner join to left outer join would work perfectly.

*Updated based on OP's comment:*

```
select facid, isnull(Partner1, 0) p1 , isnull(partner2, 0) p2, isnull(partner3, 0) p3 
FROM 
(select f.facilityId as facid, p.PartnerN as partn, cast(fp.active as int) as val
FROM @facility f
left outer join @FacilityPartner fp on f.facilityId = fp.facilityId
left outer JOIN @PartnerInfo p on p.partnerid = fp.partnerid) x
PIVOT(
avg(val)
for partn in ([partner1], [partner2],[partner3])
) as pvt
```

Result:

```
facid   p1  p2  p3
------------------
12345   1   0   0
67890   0   1   1
99999   0   0   0
```

Comment: If FacilityPartner table has an "Active" column (true/false or 0/1) how do I return 0 for that partner as if it had the falg set to zero? For example, in the updated FacilityPartner table, where second row has "false", your result would display "12345 1 0 0" instead of "12345 1 0 1"?